# How do I write this as an AngularJS $http.get?

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering, how could this be written in angularJS?

```
requests: {
    fetchUsers: function() {
        return {
            url: 'https://www.example.com/api/v2/users',
            type: 'GET',
            username: 'myemail@email.com/token',
            password: 'myAPItoken'
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an example:

Your controller:

```
var userCtrl = angular.module('UserCtrl',[]);

    userCtrl.controller('UserController',function($scope,Users){
        var getUsers = Users.fetchAll();
            getUsers.then(function(response){
               $scope.users = response;
            });
    });
```

Your service:

```
var userSrvc = angular.module('UserSrvc',[]);

userSrvc.factory("Users",function($http){

    return{
        fetchAll: function(){
            var request = $http({method:'GET', url:'https://www.example.com/api/v2/users'});
            return request;
        }
    }
});
```